# Excel VBA stop Auto Rounding

Tags: excel, vba

I have price column in which the prices are displayed in 3 decimals and 4 decimals places, for example 123.456 or 123.4357. 
So irrespective of the number of decimal places i want the value to be with only two decimals.
So i am selecting the column and in the VBA i am using Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Which is resulting me the rounded value i.e when i format 123.456 and 123.4357  to 0.00 i am getting 123.46 and 123.44 but i want it to be 123.46 and 123.43.

So just wondering is there a way we can just trim the values instead of rounding.
Please give me some sample examples.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your last sentence, first paragraph says "when i format 123.456 and 123.4357 to 0.00 i am getting 123.46 and 123.44 but i want it to be 123.46 and 123.43." Should that end with "I want it to be *123.45* and 123.43" ? That would be consistent with your request for trim function instead of rounding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel has a built-in function, trunc, that should do the trick for you.

This is what I placed in a1:b2.

```
123.456  =trunc(A1,2)
123.4357 =trunc(A2,2)
```

This will display

```
123.456  123.45
123.4357 123.43
```

Answer (score 1):

You could treat the result as a string and extract the number of characters you need as in:

`dim a as double`
dim s as string
`a = 123.4357`
s = MID(a,1,FIND(".",a))&MID(a,FIND(".",a)+1,2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built in mask that will truncate without rounding, you could instead use another column containing `=TRUNC(A1, 2)`.